# Push JUnit report to Sonar Qube

Tags: javascript, web, junit, sonarqube, template-engine

We are using some sort of custom templating engine that contains normal HTML syntax and some custom tags and among other it can contain some sort of scripting that is executed on the server side. We wrote some unit tests that prove the content of those custom templates and raise error when there are some script elements used that are forbidden.

We are using Jest as test runner and we are creating Sonar Qube test report with `jest-sonar-reporter`. I have set `sonar.tests` to point to our tests as `sonar.tests=spec`. In Sonar Qube UI under **Administration > Web area**, I have extended `sonar.web.file.suffixes` with our extension as well. When we start Sonar Qube in our deployment pipeline, I see in the logs

```
07:08:49.291 INFO: Sensor Generic Test Executions Report
07:08:49.291 WARN: Property 'sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths' is deprecated. Please use 'sonar.testExecutionReportPaths' instead.
07:08:49.291 INFO: Parsing /codebuild/output/src915641274/src/reports/test-report.xml
07:08:49.491 INFO: Imported test execution data for 0 files
07:08:49.491 INFO: Test execution data ignored for 2 unknown files, including:
/codebuild/output/src943613774/src/spec/isml.spec.js
/codebuild/output/src943613774/src/spec/files.spec.js
```

Our sonar-project.properties look like this:

```
sonar.host.url=<host_url>
sonar.login=<token>

sonar.projectKey=<project_key>
sonar.projectName=<project_name>

sonar.sources=cartridge,spec

sonar.verbose=true

sonar.inclusions=**/js/**/*.js,**/templates/**/*.isml

sonar.tests=spec
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/test-report.xml
```

In this project I have `js` and `web` as languages. If I go in Sonar Qube UI and check this project under **Measures > Coverage > Tests**, I do not see any coverage tests being imported. So my question is did I understand the JUnit coverage import wrong or am I missing something in my Sonar Qube configuration?

Comment: It appears that your test reports include _absolute_ file paths ("/codebuild/...") do those paths actually exist, or are the leading slashes in error?

Comment: I just checked generated XML report and the file paths are absolute `<file path="/codebuild/output/src560066792/src/spec/isml.spec.js">`. Does that mean my file path should begin from `spec/isml.spec.js`.

Comment: It may be that your inclusions are interfering with this. Try dropping that parameter & analyzing again

Comment: This one I should remove or comment out? `sonar.inclusions=**/js/**/*.js,**/templates/**/*.isml`. Problem is that I would get some bunch of other files in Sonar Qube that I do not want.

Comment: When you use inclusions, you're saying "analyze _only_ these files", and I believe that's excluding your tests. If you really want to narrow the set, try setting (preferably via the UI) exclusions instead.

Comment: I think we choose inclusions because the file we want to analyze at the moment are just those and if we are going with exclusions the list is going to grow out of proportions. Lets just say that inclusions make sense at this moment. I have tried to put tests as well in the inclusions, but then I get other error saying I cannot include files that have already been included.

Comment: OK. So I managed to solve this. I replaced the absolute file paths to relative ones and now the Unit tests are being imported to the Sonar Qube. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should probably post your answer _as_ an answer, not as an annotated part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The `[value]` in JUnit report at `<file path="[value]">`, needs to be relative to the `sonar.tests=` value.

```
project
├── src
│   └── ...
└── spec
    ├── isml.spec.js
    └── files.spec.js
```

So in my case I used sed command and trimmed the "absolute" part of the path.